# How to get selected value in observableArrayList type from ChoiceBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, jcombobox, observablelist

This question is similar to other questions about ChoiceBox in JavaFX, but I have something else done in my code.
I have class with following elements:

```
    package application;

public class ControllerRegister extends Main implements Initializable  {

@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> cbSuppliers;
private ArrayList<String> suppliers = new ArrayList<String>();

public ControllerRegister() throws SQLException {/*....*/}

@FXML //controller method
void buttonOnAction2(ActionEvent event2) throws IOException, SQLException {
    //push some button and then get value of choicebox
    setStrTabDat() 
    /*....*/
}

public static void setStrTabDat(){ //my attempts to show selected value from ChoiceBox
    ObservableList<String> outputOl = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     ChoiceBox<String> cbSuppliers = new ChoiceBox<String>();
     outputOl = cbSuppliers.getItems();
     outputOl.addAll(cbSuppliers.getValue());
     String output = cbSuppliers.getValue();
     System.out.println("output string: "+output);
     System.out.println("output by method: " +cbSuppliers.getItems());
     System.out.println("output observList: "+outputOl.toString());
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(suppliers);
    cbSuppliers.setItems(list);
    cbSuppliers.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
}
}
```

As can you see in setStrTabDat() method there are my attempts to print selected value from ChoiceBox, but output of all three Sytem.out.prints is 'null'.. I know the solution is close to me, so please advice me what I should do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try [THIS LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/choice-box.htm). Here they explain:

- How to create ChoiceBox();
- How to use one
- How to add listeners
- How to retrieve data

Basically they explain everything that you need to know about it.

Good luck :)

Best regards,
Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: Thanks, Your proposal led me to a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution is to add to ChoiceBox listener in initialize() method like this:

```
    @Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(suppliers);
    cbSuppliers.setItems(list);
    cbSuppliers.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    //and listener:
    cbSuppliers.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number2) {
    System.out.println(cbSuppliers.getItems().get((Integer) number2));
    }
    });
}
```